# How remove gross errors from time series?

Tags: time-series, data-cleaning

I have a long time series of 5min water level data from wells. The series contain measurement errors that are easily viewed in time-series plots.

[water level time series plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDWXi.png)

```
head(data)
# A tibble: 229,120 x 4
   date                 temp P_comp_m alt_m
   <dttm>              <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2016-06-10 11:50:00  21.8     1.09 1008.
 2 2016-06-10 11:55:00  21.2     1.07 1008.
 3 2016-06-10 12:00:00  21.1     1.06 1008.
 4 2016-06-10 12:05:00  21.1     1.05 1008.
 5 2016-06-10 12:10:00  21.9     1.05 1008.
 6 2016-06-10 12:15:00  21.8     1.04 1008.
 7 2016-06-10 12:20:00  21.7     1.03 1008.
 8 2016-06-10 12:25:00  21.6     1.03 1008.
 9 2016-06-10 12:30:00  21.5     1.02 1008.
10 2016-06-10 12:35:00  21.5     1.01 1008.
# ... with 229,110 more rows
```

Due to the volume of data I wish to automate the data cleaning process. Currently, I am removing spurious data manually with R tidyverse tools.

```
data[between(data$date, 
                 as_datetime("2016-11-27 17:00:00"),
                 as_datetime("2016-11-29 01:50:00")),] <- data %>% 
  filter(between(date, as_datetime("2016-11-27 17:00:00"),
                 as_datetime("2016-11-29 01:50:00"))) %>% 
  mutate(temp = NA,                                        # temperature column 
         P_comp_m = NA,                                    # pressure
         alt_m = NA)                                       # altitude
```

Can anyone provide suggestions to automate the task?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the task if you can articulate/express the criteria for "spurious" data. Or you can automate a part of it: e.g. pick the manually choose/pick the times you considered the data is spurious, put them into a vector/list and set a process to automatically remove these datapoints from the data (based on manually created list).